# Add search to slider in wordpress sites

Tags: wordpress

How to add the search box on slider in wordpress?
same as this site: http://www.wikiform.org/

Comment: which slider you are using??? revolution slider???

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on the slider you're using.
but here's a basic structure of WordPress search which uses the default search function.

```
<form action="" method="get">
search: <input type="text" name="s"><br>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

yoursiteurl.com/?s=test